# Setting up MX records with GoDaddy and Rackspace, stuck at validating

Tags: email, web-server, email-server, mx-record

I have my domain with GoDaddy and my web server with Rackspace.

I created 2 forwarding emails on GoDaddy (`email1@example.com and email2@example.com`) pointing at `mypersonalemail@mailprovider`

but it keeps stucking at "**validating MX records**"

I contacted both hosts and said that I need to add my web server providers `MX` records to my domain... Did i get it correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to correct the MX records in your DNS which is probably hosted on your server at Rackspace.  You can locate the MX records you need in the Email Control Center.  Here is a guide to do so:
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5444

Answer (score 1):

We need more clarification to help you..

If your Name Servers point to Godaddy and your A records point to Rackspace and you purchased the email hosting on godaddy (which it sounds like you did to set up forwarders) then you most likely have the MX records set to something like smtp.secureserver.net (godaddy's mail servers), which just sounds like a complete mess.

Now most people will typically point the NS to Rackspace, then they will manage the DNS on rackspace and have the email hosted on rackspace and then use fowarders in that email system to whatever address you want. If this is your setup, then you will need to set up MX records on rackspace to point to rackspace mail servers, or point them back to godaddy to use their email servers.

Personally, I would just use Google Apps to host the email, and follow their instructions.

To get a better understanding how MX records work, here's some homework for you to go over.

[MX Records](http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/mxrecords/)

[MX Records Video](http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/unlocktheinboxtv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I 100% understand the question but if you need to set up new email accounts.

On godaddy create the mx records. That tells email servers where to forward your email to. You might want to put some other dns entries in there too?

On rackspace create the email accounts.

Check that the mx records are pointing to rackspace

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/

and you should be good to go.